# Invoking a Lambda function that has a Python library dependency in Docker container, deployed with Zappa; 500 response code error

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, serverless, zappa, feast

I am looking to invoke AWS Lambda functions, deployed using Zappa. The lambda functions will have dependencies that are too large for the usual zip file approach (even with `slim_handler : true`).

To do this I am using Zappa with Docker containers, where the container holds the larger dependencies and the Lambda functions call upon the container as needed.

The application is a Flask app, with the usual `app.py` code that routes to a function. Deploying a dockerized flask app with Zappa is pretty straightforward, and I can do this successfully, as long as there is only vanilla Python in the `app.py`. But as soon as I add Python that depends on a library, I get the following error when attempting to invoke the Lambda function via the AWS API Gateway (as setup by Zappa):

```
Warning! Status check on the deployed lambda failed. A GET request to '/' yielded a 500 response code.
```

Here are the steps I am taking. I am using Feast as the Python library I want to work, with the dockerized Flask app pushed to Lambda with Zappa.

I Create the **Dockerfile** that works alongside Zappa for deploying to AWS Lambda.

I am using the steps outlined [here](https://ianwhitestone.work/zappa-serverless-docker/) to create this Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-python:3.8

ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/var/task/"

COPY ./ ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Setup Python environment
RUN pip install pipenv

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Grab the zappa handler.py and put it in the working directory
RUN ZAPPA_HANDLER_PATH=$( \
    python -c "from zappa import handler; print (handler.__file__)" \
    ) \
    && echo $ZAPPA_HANDLER_PATH \
    && cp $ZAPPA_HANDLER_PATH ${FUNCTION_DIR}

CMD ["handler.lambda_handler"]
```

Briefly, this uses a base image provided by AWS, copies my application code into the image, and sets up my Python environment with `pipenv`. The Zappa specific steps are at the bottom, where `handler.py` is manually added to the Docker image. "The lambda_handler function contains all the Zappa magic that routes API Gateway requests to the corresponding Flask function." The handler is specified in the `CMD` so that it runs whenever a Docker container using this image is started.

Here is my requirements.txt file:

```
zappa
flask
feast
```

Since I want Feast to be available, I install this inside the virtual environment:

**Installing FEAST**

These steps are from [here](https://docs.feast.dev/quickstart):

Install Feast:

```
pip install feast
```

Create a Feature Repo:

```
feast init feature_repo
cd feature_repo
```

Register feature definitions and deployed feature store:

```
feast apply
```

Load features into my online store:

```
CURRENT_TIME=$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
feast materialize-incremental $CURRENT_TIME
```

To test that Feast will be successfully deployed on Lambda I will fetch the feature vectors for inference over the AWS API Gateway, by invoking a Lambda Function over AWS. So I need the necessary Feast code callable by Flask:

**Fetching Feature Vectors for Inference**

I set up the Feast code inside the usual Flask `app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
    
from feast import FeatureStore

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():

    store = FeatureStore(repo_path="feature_repo/")

    feature_vector = store.get_online_features(
        feature_refs=[
            "driver_hourly_stats:conv_rate",
            "driver_hourly_stats:acc_rate",
            "driver_hourly_stats:avg_daily_trips",
        ],
        entity_rows=[{"driver_id": 1001}],
    ).to_dict()

    return feature_vector

# We only need this for local development.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The expected response from this is:

```
{
    'driver_id': [1001],
    'driver_hourly_stats__conv_rate': [0.49274],
    'driver_hourly_stats__acc_rate': [0.92743],
    'driver_hourly_stats__avg_daily_trips': [72],
}
```

I also **install Zappa** inside the virtual environment:

```
pipenv install zappa
```

...here is my `zappa_settings.json`:

```
"zappa_test": {
    "app_function": "app.app",
    "project_name": "app",
    "runtime": "python3.8",
    "s3_bucket": "zappa-f8s0d8fs0df",
    "aws_region" : "us-east-2",
    "lambda_description": "Zappa + Docker + Flask"
}
```

*The S3 bucket number shown here is fake*.

Also installing Flask inside the virtual environment:

```
pipenv install flask
```

**Building the Image**

I run the following to build the image:

```
zappa save-python-settings-file zappa_test
docker build -t zappa_test:latest .
```

I then **Push to ECR**:

```
aws ecr create-repository --repository-name zappa_test --image-scanning-configuration scanOnPush=true
```

**Re-Tag the Image**:

```
docker tag zappa_test:latest XXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/zappa_test:latest
```

**Get authenticated to push to ECR**:

```
aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin XXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

...and **push the image**:

```
docker push XXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/zappa_test:latest
```

Finally, I deploy the lambda function:

```
zappa deploy zappa_test -d XXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/zappa_test
```

So altogether, this is how one uses Zappa to push a docker image to AWS Lambda in order to invoke a lambda function over the AWS API Gateway. In this case, I am trying to invoke a lambda function that fetches Feast data via Flask, with the dependencies made available inside a Docker container.

But, upon running the `deploy` command I get:

```
Warning! Status check on the deployed lambda failed. A GET request to '/' yielded a 500 response code.
```

IMPORTANT:

I have confirmed that all of these steps work if I put something simple inside the `app.py` like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello, world!", 200
```

Everything is credentialized on AWS correctly, the image deploys, and I can call it perfectly through the API endpoint provided by Zappa (via AWS Gateway). I only get the mentioned error when I put the Feast code inside `app.py`, as I've shown above.

Comment: It's telling you that you have a 500 server error, `GET request to '/' yielded a 500 response code`, check the log and what does error say?

Comment: @monkut why are you repeating the error to me. I wrote the question, you don’t think I know what the error says?

Comment: You need to share the content of the error by looking at the log and posting it here.  The reason why it's failing is in the log.  Share that and we can help.  In zappa you can use `zappa tail` to display the log, but is also visible via cloudwatch.

Comment: Check the logs of Lambda on the CloudWatch, not the zappa log. I have this but a 502 and the logs of Lambda gave me clues how I can resolve my issues.